# Order status doesn't change to "Complete" after shipping and invoicing

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-status, magento2.2.4

I'm having this issue on Magento 2.2.4:

We're using for the store only one payment module (Mercado Pago), which has many different payment methods, when the customer pays with credit card as payment method, the order goes through the whole process with no problems, but when they pay with "Pagofacil" (one of the other payment methods of the module) the order stays in "Processing" status.

I've checked every order with this problem and all of them have invoice and have been shipped, also, they still have the "hold" option, so they're not on hold.

I thought it might be something with the payment method "Pagofacil", but the same issue happens with one order paid with credit card, only that in this case, the first time the payment was rejected and after a second try it was accredited but it remained in "Processing" status (Invoice and shipping completed).

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you give a try with Disable your payment module for while than place order with default methods such as COD than create shipment and invoice. Than check if status is changed complete or not.

Comment: how about check out error logs (you might have to enable these from the backend) and then once enable, do check if you can spot something related to the shipping action